# Expression Tree: Get property value of dynamic object

Tags: c#, reflection

I have list of dynamic objects where I want to query by custom property. In other words, it would look like this if I wasn't going for reflection:

```cs
IEnumerable<User> FilterUsers(IEnumerable<User> users, string selectedValue)
{
    users.Where(user => user.Name == selectedValue);
}
```

So far I've come up with the following implementation that works if `users` is typed:

```cs
IEnumerable<User> FilterUsers(IEnumerable<User> users, string selectedField, string selectedValue)
{
    LabelTarget returnTarget = Expression.Label(typeof(bool));
    ParameterExpression userParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User));
    MemberExpression userSelectedField = Expression.Property(userParameter, selectedField);
    Expression test = Expression.Equal(userSelectedField, Expression.Constant(selectedValue));
    Expression iftrue = Expression.Return(returnTarget, Expression.Constant(true));
    Expression iffalse = Expression.Return(returnTarget, Expression.Constant(false));

    var ex = Expression.Block(
        Expression.IfThenElse(test, iftrue, iffalse),
        Expression.Label(returnTarget, Expression.Constant(false)));

    var whereClause = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, bool>>(
        ex,
        new ParameterExpression[] { userParameter }
    ).Compile();

    return users.Where(user => whereClause(user));
}
```

What I am really trying to do is to make users dynamic object:

```cs
IEnumerable<dynamic> FilterUsers(IEnumerable<dynamic> users, string selectedField, string selectedValue) {
    // ...
    ParameterExpression userParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object)); // ???
    MemberExpression userSelectedField = Expression.Property(userParameter, selectedField); // throws
    // ...
}
```

This throws the following exception: `Instance property 'Name' is not defined for type 'System.Object' (Parameter 'propertyName')`. What am I missing?

Alternatively, how can I use `Dictionary<string, object>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dynamic` here doesn't get you much: you'd be better off using generics if you can:

```
IEnumerable<T> FilterUsers<T>(IEnumerable<T> users, string selectedField, string selectedValue)
{
    var userParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var userSelectedField = Expression.Property(userParameter, selectedField);
    // etc...
}
```

---

If you do need to use `dynamic`, then you'll need to get the runtime type of each user, using `.GetType()`. However bear in mind that there's nothing stopping someone from passing in an `IEnumerable` containing lots of different types of object, and they don't all have to have a property called `selectedField`!

Or, they might pass in lots of different types of object, each of one has a property called `selectedField`, but they're distinct properties (e.g. `class A { public string Foo { get; set; } }` and `class B { public string Foo { get; set; } }` -- those two `Foo` properties are distinct).

So you'll have to call `.GetType()` on each one of them, which means you won't be able to get the performance benefits of using compiled expressions.

If you can guarantee that all elements have the same type, you can do something like:

```
private static IEnumerable<dynamic> FilterCollection(IEnumerable<dynamic> collection, string property, string value)
{
    if (!collection.Any()) return collection;
    var collectionItemType = collection.First().GetType();
    var userParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    var convertedUser = Expression.Convert(userParameter, collectionItemType);
    var userSelectedField = Expression.Property(convertedUser, selectedField);
    ...
}
```

Beware however that you're enumerating `users` twice, which is probably a bad thing. You might do better to get the `IEnumerator` yourself and work with it explicitly.

Comment: `user` is generated by a builder as `new { ... }` - no need to worry about funky data, but it's not possible to create specific types for all possible variations.
Can I do it as:

```cs
IEnumerable<dynamic> FilterUsers(IEnumerable<dynamic> users, string selectedField, string selectedValue)
{
  var firstUser = users.FirstOrDefault();
  if (firstUser == null) return Enumerable.Empty<dynamic>();
  // all should have the same structure
  var userParameter = Expression.Parameter(firstUser.GetType());
  var userSelectedField = Expression.Property(userParameter, selectedField);
}
```

Comment: Yep that should work if they're all the same type. You might need to declare the parameter of type object and add an Expression.Convert to that type

Comment: There was an improvement, but it still throws an exception at different place. More details here: https://pastebin.com/0UHegqKg

Comment: @Arvigeus See the second part of my previous comment: "*You might need to declare the parameter of type object and add an Expression.Convert to that type*"

Comment: Can you post this as an answer, so I can mark it as accepted? https://pastebin.com/sgG4YgpD

Answer (score 1):

As @canton7 said you should be using a generic method. I also see in your question you specified you're looking for *properties*, why not use regular old reflection?

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FilterItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string property, string value)
{
  var prop = typeof(T).GetProperties().First(p => p.Name == property);      
  return items.Where(i => prop.GetValue(i).ToString().Contains(value));
}
```

Of course that code should be enhanced to handle different errors....

Comment: Speed, most likely. In your case, it would be better to use `typeof(T)` rather than `items.First().GetType()`, in case the items have different types

Comment: @canton7 I haven't really worked with the `Expression` namespace before so I could be doing something wrong but, iterating 1,000 times over my method and over his took 6 and 180 ms on average for 3 runs. It doesn't look like Expression is faster. Thanks for pointing out the typof(T) also... updating answer.